# How do I prevent a SaveFileDialog from prompting twice to replace/overwrite a file?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, savefiledialog, .net-4.7.2

How can I stop a `System.Windows.Forms.SaveFileDialog` from prompting twice to replace a selected file, and instead prompt only once?

Either I'm missing something, there's something wrong with my install, or the default behaviour is just dumb.

```
var saveFileDialog = new SaveFileDialog();
saveFileDialog.ShowDialog();
// User selects file and clicks "Save" within the dialog
```

I'm not doing anything special at all, this is in an empty Windows Forms project, targeting .NET Framework 4.7.2.

Edit: Added full Program.cs

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace WindowsFormsApp1
{
    static class Program
    {
        /// <summary>
        /// The main entry point for the application.
        /// </summary>
        [STAThread]
        static void Main()
        {
            Application.EnableVisualStyles();
            Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);

            var saveFileDialog = new SaveFileDialog();
            saveFileDialog.ShowDialog();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: That code should only show the question once, are you sure that is all of the code? I tried the code in a small test project and when selecting an existing file I get the overwrite question, once. Can you please post a [mcve] so that we can be sure we're not missing anything?

Comment: "wrong with my install" is a high probability on a programmer's machine.  The dialog loads the shell extensions, programmers tend to have a lot of them and not always well tested.  Just verify if this repeats in another program, test both c:\windows\system32\notepad.exe and c:\windows\syswow64\notepad.exe, File > Save As.  Find/disable the evildoer with SysInternals' AutoRuns utility.

Comment: @HansPassant That expectedly prevents the overwrite prompt from showing altogether. (referring to previous comment). I will test as you've suggested and report back.

Comment: @HansPassant Notepad 32 or 64-bit doesn't exhibit the same behaviour. But I have suspicions that this is an issue limited to this machine, seeing that LasseVågsætherKarlsen could not replicate the problem.

Comment: @HansPassant et al, this is most definitely a bug. My machine just upgraded to the latest windows build last night and this behavior started happening on old C# applications that were not even recompiled.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This seems to be a bug in the latest .Net version.
It does not happen on Windows builds prior to 10.0.17763

Comment: This .NET bug is fixed by KB4481031 (https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/4481031/january-22-2019-kb4481031).  Currently, you have to go to Windows Update and click "Check for updates" to get it to download and install.